# How can I see comma in attribute table?

Tags: qgis

I want to see comma instead off points in my attribute table.

What happens is: When I import TXT or CSV there´s an option to use comma as decimal delimiter but after the importation I only see points as decimal delimiter.

What do I need to do?

Source CSV

[image]

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: what is your locale set to?

Comment: Please check [QGIS uses comma as decimal separator for shapefile attribute data](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8332)

Answer (score 7):

The settings you can control in the "Add delimited text layer" dialog is how the .csv file is being interpreted by QGIS when reading it. If your original file has a comma as decimal point (which it apparently has) this can be specified here.

After that however QGIS doesn't care about the file format any more and represents all decimal numbers in the same way (*display* format), wherever they may come from.

To control the *display* of decimal points, go to Settings -> Options -> General and check "Override System Locale" and switch the Locale to your preferred one. E.g. Italian or German (Germany) has comma as thousands separator.